# IOException while using threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, file

```
using System.Numerics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Fibonacci_cs
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i;
            var ausgabe = Task.Factory.StartNew((() => {}));
            BigInteger x, y = 1, z = 1;
            for (i = 1; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
            {
                x = y;
                Task.WaitAll();
                y = z;
                Task.Factory.StartNew((() => { z = BigInteger.Add(x, y); }));
                Task.Factory.StartNew((() =>
                {
                    if (ausgabe.IsCompleted)
                    {
                        ausgabe = Task.Factory.StartNew((() =>
                        {
                            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"A:\Fibonacci.txt"))
                            {
                                file.WriteLine("i: " + i);
                                file.WriteLine("z: " + z);
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                }));
            }

            Task.WaitAll();
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
                new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"A:\Fibonacci.txt"))
            {
                file.WriteLine("i: " + i);
                file.WriteLine("z: " + z);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting a System.IO.IOException because the file is "in use". What am I missing? Does the process not close the file after using?

I don't have more details, except that I have to use it this way.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to write to the same file at the same time from different threads.

Comment: The file is accessed through multiple threads (that execute the Tasks you create) that try to write to it. Why are you doing that?

Comment: File writing operation are not thread safe, you should be doing this another way.

Comment: And why are you calling Task.WaitAll without passing any tasks to it? That's pointless, since it won't wait at all.

Comment: What is all this Task Stuff supposed to do here?

Comment: You need a tutorial. Many basic misunderstandings. This exception is not the only bug, this is completely not working. You need someone explaining the basics and how to go about things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file access operations are all happening at the same time. I recommend that you create the `StreamWriter` outside of your loop and use `lock` on this stream object where you have your using block.

e.g.

```
var streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"A:\Fibonacci.txt");
//for loop
    lock (streamWriter)
    {
        streamWriter.WriteLine("i: " + i);
        streamWriter.WriteLine("z: " + z);
    }
```